# Is previewing possible composite documents without sending it out by eMail

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

Is it necessary to send out an eMail to recipients to fill a template with tabs?

At the moment I create an envelope with `status=sent` that will obviously sent the filled documents to recipients. I would not like to send the document's, when creating.

If I use `status=created` the preview shows just empty documents. The templates are not filled with the tabs and not send.

How can I preview, but not sent an eMail. And sent when I think I am ready. In total the recipient would just get on eMail to sign their documents.

```
{
"emailSubject": "DocuSign: Multi Document",
"status": "sent",
"eventNotification": {
    "url": "http://fake.com",
    "envelopeEvents": [
        {
            "envelopeEventStatusCode": "Completed"
        }
    ],
    "recipientEvents": [
        {
            "recipientEventStatusCode": "Completed"
        }
    ]
},
"brandId": "11111-my-brand-id---1111",
"compositeTemplates": [
    {
        "serverTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": 1,
                "templateId": "myTemplate-id-1"
            }
        ],
        "inlineTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": 1,
                "recipients": {
                    "signers": [
                        {
                            "email": "adv+docusign@test.test",
                            "name": "Dev",
                            "recipientId": 1,
                            "roleName": "Advisor",
                            "tabs": {
                                "textTabs": [
                                    {
                                        "tabLabel": "Subscription_Amount",
                                        "value": "100000",
                                        "documentId": 1
                                    }
                                ],
                                "radioGroupTabs": []
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "serverTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": 2,
                "templateId": "myTemplate-id-2"
            }
        ],
        "inlineTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": 2,
                "recipients": {
                    "signers": [
                        {
                            "email": "adv+docusign@test.test",
                            "name": "Dev",
                            "recipientId": 1,
                            "roleName": "Advisor",
                            "tabs": {
                                "textTabs": [
                                    {
                                        "tabLabel": "Subscription_Amount",
                                        "value": "100000",
                                        "documentId": 1
                                    }
                                ],
                                "radioGroupTabs": []
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "serverTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": 3,
                "templateId": "myTemplate-id-3"
            }
        ],
        "inlineTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": 3,
                "recipients": {
                    "signers": [
                        {
                            "email": "other+docusign@test.test",
                            "name": "Dev",
                            "recipientId": 1,
                            "roleName": "Other",
                            "tabs": {
                                "textTabs": [
                                    {
                                        "tabLabel": "Subscription_Amount",
                                        "value": "100000",
                                        "documentId": 1
                                    }
                                ],
                                "radioGroupTabs": []
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

Sending (short version)

```
{
   emailSubject: 'DocuSign: Multi Document',
   status: 'sent',
   eventNotification:
    exports {
      url: 'https://host/o/fsg11/hook',
      envelopeEvents: [ [Object] ],
      recipientEvents: [ [Object] ] },
   brandId: 'brand-id',
   compositeTemplates:
    [ { serverTemplates: [Object], inlineTemplates: [Object] },
      { serverTemplates: [Object], inlineTemplates: [Object] },
      { serverTemplates: [Object], inlineTemplates: [Object] } ] 
}
```

Receiving

```
{
    envelopeId: 'envelope-id',
    status: 'sent',
    statusDateTime: '2017-06-13T01:10:08.3100000Z',
    uri: '/envelopes/envelope-id'
}
```

Comment: Please show us the json request you are using to create the envelope. You should be able to preview the envelope if you set `status=created`. You probably are not passing the correct request parameters.

Comment: @CodingDawg that is the JSON, which is created by createEnvelope() function from DocuSigns node.js package. If I change it to `status=created`, the templates won't be filled.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure the `tabLabel`, `recipientId` and `documentId`  match the server templates values. The tabs should be created successfully once those values are correct.

You can obtain those values using the [listTemplateDocuments](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Templates/TemplateDocuments/) && [listTemplateRecipients](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Templates/TemplateRecipients/list/) apis.

For **documentId**

> GET https://demo.docusign.net/v2/accounts/{accountId}/templates/{templateId}/documents

For **tabLabel**, **recipientId**

> GET https://demo.docusign.net/v2/accounts/{accountId}/templates/{templateId}/recipients?include_tabs=true

Comment: they id's are all matching to the templates I have on DocuSign. I have replaced them here due to privacy (my client is pretty strict) on that.

Comment: Can you please post the response of your  listTemplateDocuments && listTemplateRecipients api calls. You can scrub the sensitive Data.

Comment: Do your Templates have any existing tabs? If so, are they appearing on the Envelope. Is your problem limited to the new tabs you are adding? Can you please clarify.

Comment: the templates have tabs and they are actually filed, when the unwanted email is sent.

Comment: Can you please share the response from listTemplateDocuments && listTemplateRecipients api calls. Also please share the envelopeId that you have created.

Comment: Maybe it would be easier if you could share how to do that with node.js an example like on the README https://github.com/docusign/DocuSign-Node-Client

Comment: Can you share your templateId, it would be easier for me to look it up in our system.

Comment: The envelope has 126 tabs. What is the issue with those tabs?

Comment: As said, preview worked when using status=sent. When changing some tiny things the eMail to recipients was sent again.

Comment: What do you mean by changing tiny things. How are you changing? Which api call are you using? Can you please show us your request.

Comment: What I am doing now is status=created. When I try to preview using the getDocument function in docusign-esign nodejs package. I am not seeing the document with fields filled. That function does not have a parameter include_tabs. The function hits the endpoint /v2/accounts/{accountId}/templates/{templateId}/documents/{documentId}

Comment: GetTemplateDocument api does not have an option to show the tabs. It will only show the plain document. See Documentation [here](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Templates/TemplateDocuments/get/)

Comment: If you want to see the Tabs, use [getTemplateRecipients](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Templates/TemplateRecipients/list/) api. Make sure you pass the include_tabs querystring parameter. **v2/accounts/{accountId}/templates/{templateId}/recipients?include_tabs=true**

Comment: sorry... copied the wrong endpoint: I am using EnvelopApi.getDocument, which hits: /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/{documentId}

Comment: I would like to get the PDF filled with the tabs for that envelopeId/documentId... I am not sure if templates/templateId/recipient would work. Later I am going to have many different recipients for the same template which can be combined with other templates in different envelopes.

Comment: is there another way to communicate, on the phone or chat maybe. Weather DocuSign is just not providing or I am missing the right spot in the documentations.

Comment: If you want the PDF fillled with Tabs then envelope should be sent and recipients will have to sign it.. Without signing tabs will not appear on the PDF .... Docusign does not offer such a preview option.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146774/discussion-between-vik-and-codingdawg).

Comment: So there are two possibilities. 1. combining GetDocument and GetTemplateRecipient that would build the PDF.
2. SenderView. - whereas SenderView is giving me an error: message: "Invalid envelope status. Envelope not completed."
To combine GetDocument/GetTemplateRecipient I would need to research if that really would be an applicable solution -- in general it looks like previewing documents using the API is not possible before sending out eMail

Comment: Please accept and upvote this answer if it answered your initial question... If you need additional help with CreateSenderView then please post a new question with more details... Your JSON request .. the api call you are making etc ..

Comment: Unfortunately this did not answer my question. I would like upvote, when I am sure that works. So next person reading this can rely on it. I appreciate your comment's. Regarding CreateSenderView, I just use the DocuSign ApiExplorer... you might get the JSON request from that API explorer. for not completed envelope's createSenderView is not working... so that actually answers my question with NO. I need to test GetDocument/GetTemplateRecipient to have a positive or negative answer to my question. Thanks @CodingDawg