# Using docusign EnvelopeViews: createSender as preview

Tags: docusignapi

createSender creates a URL, which I would like to use to let the sender preview the document before it's send out. Hence the documents are created using templates and and the API.
The link which is created would lead me out of my UI. Does the user need to sign in? Future plan is to have many user's, which have no DocuSign account.

Answer (score 1):

For [embedded sending](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/embedding-docusign#EmbeddedSending) Your app will have to authenticate the user. If you are doing a [Service Integration](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#common-service) then your Api account will be used as the sender.

Once the sending url is generated using the [createSenderView](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createSender/) api, there is no authentication required to access the URL.

You also have an option to build a [User Application](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#common-user) using the docusign Api where your App can support sending from multiple accounts.

Comment: createSenderView which is described in the documents as *EnvelopeViews: createSender* is requiring an authentication. I am using a demo account, does this make a difference?

Comment: All docusign api calls require authentication.

Comment: createSenderView creates a non api URL. Which I would like to access without authentication, possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible. You can just try accessing the generated URL in a browser. It should not prompt for authentication.

Comment: I tried that a few times. that's why I am asking if it has to do with the demo account I am using. The generated URL is always prompting for login.

Comment: I have to see your code to tell why the generated URL is always prompting for login. Please show us your api calls and request for those calls.

Answer (score 0):

The createSenderView requires that the person is a DocuSign user (with their own account and password).

Only DocuSign users can send. We charge for sending, not for signing or receiving.

What exactly do you want to preview? (And why?)

- the documents themselves? Use the [EnvelopeDocuments resource.](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/) You can also preview [the thumbnails of the documents.](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/getPageImages/)
- the documents with the "fields" ("tabs") that indicate where people will sign? I'm not sure that is do-able.
- or the recipients and their routing order? Use [EnvelopeRecipients: list](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/list/) method.

**Added**

Another solution is to use a dummy certified delivery "recipient". Add this recipient as the first recipient. This will block the envelope from proceeding on the recipient routing.

Then get the envelope's documents to show as a preview.

Then, if ok, alter the envelope's recipients to remove the certified delivery recipient. The envelope will then continue on with the first "real" recipient.

Comment: We are using multi-tenant API and we will have one DocuSign account that acts on the behalf of tenants of our API. Tenant's can create document's on our API documents based on templates (existing and labelled on DocuSign). The tenants need a preview before sending out to signers. A draft envelope on DocuSign won't show a filled document when I get the documents.
CodingDawg answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44437245/is-previewing-possible-composite-documents-without-sending-it-out-by-email) to use 1. createSenderView or 2. combining GetDocument and GetTemplateRecipient.

Comment: Simpler solutions are welcome or maybe it is somehow possible to use [EnvelopeDocuments Resource](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeDocuments/) for envelopes in status draft/created

Comment: Thank you @larry-k, what is a dummy certified delivery recipient. Do you have examples?

Comment: Please ask as a new question. And some upvotes would be appreciated for the answers that you find helpful.

Comment: I would definitely upvote if I get to a solution, but I am actually spending hours to figure out how the answers would work for me. I could not add dummy certified delivery. The API reference is mentioning it, but it is not implemented in the DocuSign node sdk so after hours of trials I could not figure out if that works. Beside's I think at the moment the correct answer would be a downloadable preview in draft status of an envelope is not possible.

Comment: Please post a new question with your code that is using the node SDK. It is hard for us to figure out the issue without seeing your code.  Please be as specific as possibile. Show what worked and what did not work. See [how to ask](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page. Please help us help you.